# Schema.org mark up offer for specific type of user

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I am adding some schema.org microdata to a product details web page.

I have added the product entity and have various offers associated with it.

How do I indicate that one Offer is valid for any user and that another Offer is a members' only discounted price?

Schema.org indicates that I might be able to use a BusinessEntityType for this:
http://schema.org/BusinessEntityType

Which points to - maybe - good relations Enduser

http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Enduser

But here the trail goes cold - I'm not sure how to add an Enduser as the BusinessEntityType, nor how to mark each Enduser as either a 'member' type or 'non-member' type.

Here is a snippet from the product, representing one Offer - I'd like this to be for any non-member user.

```
<div class="price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
        <meta itemprop="valueAddedTaxIncluded" content="false" />
        <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP">£</span><span itemprop="price">2.76</span><span class="vat-pricing-wrap"> excl VAT</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Another snippet - I'd like this to be an exclusive members' only Offer.

```
<div class="price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
        <meta itemprop="valueAddedTaxIncluded" content="false" />
        <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP">£</span><span itemprop="price">1.76</span><span class="vat-pricing-wrap"> excl VAT</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The expected value for the [`eligibleCustomerType`](http://schema.org/eligibleCustomerType) property is an enumeration of the [`BusinessEntityType`](http://schema.org/BusinessEntityType) type.

Schema.org lists four values ([…`Business`](http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Business), […`Enduser`](http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Enduser), […`PublicInstitution`](http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PublicInstitution), […`Reseller`](http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Reseller)) from the GoodRelations vocabulary. GoodRelations itself [doesn’t define more values](http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/goodrelations/v1#BusinessEntityType).

As these four values don’t seem to be suitable for your case, the best way would be to find a suitable type defined by someone else. If there’s no such type, the "clean" way would be to use your own type, e.g. (assuming that you control example.com):

```html
<link itemprop="eligibleCustomerType" href="http://example.com/types/Member" />
```

The not-so-clean way would be to use a string value instead (Schema.org allows this for all their properties), e.g.:

```html
<meta itemprop="eligibleCustomerType" content="Member" />
```